# How to identify resource and normal accounts in LDAP using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

We use Microsoft LDAP in our organization. We have users which are used by humans and running automation scripts.

I ain't familiar with LDAP although I have to write a script which should do the following:

- Get all users from the ad group and I use the following `Get-ADGroupMember` to get all users.
- In my script I want to find out which all users belong to "automation".

I tried to get the properties for users in LDAP via `Get-ADUser`for a system user and normal user but I can't find any differences.

Any ideas how I can identify if an user is a resource account or a normal user?

Comment: What is "automation"? An LDAP field? A group? Unless you specify when the account is created there is no difference between a normal user and one which is used for services/automation. That's what groups and custom fields are for...

Comment: user ID which are mainly used for running automation scripts, builds and not assigned to real users.

Comment: What is the difference between a "normal" and an "automation" user? I think so that's the sam -> an an AD User not? So you would need an identifier. For example a value inside an AD Attribute or something.

Comment: If there's no LDAP attribute/field whcih denotes such users then you'll have to compare the UID to a list of every known user which is used for automation.

Comment: Usually, those "automation" users are called something like `svc_purpose` to distinghuish them from "real" users. Also you could add them to a specified OU or set an otherwise unuser property on them so it's easy to filter them out; lots of options.